# Can I attach screen after system restart?

Tags: linux, vim, gnu-screen

I used to create a screen and use vim to trace source code.
I usually use the commands to create, detach and attach a screen to keep my vim status.

`$ screen -S vim_src1`

`[CTRL+a] d` to detach the screen

`$ screen -r vim_src1`

However, screen status will be killed after system restart.
Can I attach screen after system restart?

Answer (score 2):

After a *system restart* there is no `screen` session to *attach*.  You can certainly *create* a new session.

A `screen` session that you *could* attach has been running since you detached it.  A system restart kills all of the processes (including those running in `screen`).

In desktop environments, you may see occasional support for saving "session" state.  Doing that relies upon *each* application to save its *state* when asked, e.g., on system shutdown.  That can be workable for large GUI applications (which are designed to handle events). But in contrast, `screen` is mostly used for *shell* applications where this is done rarely.

Rather than require *each* application to save/restore itself, it is conceivable that the operating system could be designed to do this.  But that does not appear to be the case for the systems we are using.

Further reading:

- [How to Automatically Remember Running Applications from Your Last Session in Ubuntu 14.04](http://www.howtogeek.com/203952/how-to-automatically-remember-running-applications-from-your-last-session-in-ubuntu-14.04/?PageSpeed=noscript)
- [How can I keep restore for apps in Lion without having session restore when I log in?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22656/how-can-i-keep-restore-for-apps-in-lion-without-having-session-restore-when-i-lo)

Comment: Yes, I known the concepts. Do you know any method to recover screen status after system restart?

Answer (score 0):

I can interpret your answer in a few ways, because I'm not 100% certain what your objective is. I'll try to give the two most obvious options I'm aware of.

You can configure your screen session with ~/.screenrc so it always launches the same with, with labels and for screens, and it will even launch applications for you.  For example:

```
defutf8 on
caption always "%{= kK} %{K}%-w%{+b w}%51>%n %t%{= K}%+w%<%-=%{= kK} me@localhost | %{w}20%y-%m-%d %{w}%0c:%s %{-}"
shelltitle '$|$'
defscrollback 10000
termcap xterm|xterms|xs ti=\E7\E[?47l
terminfo xterm|xterms|xs ti=\E7\E[?47l
startup_message off
screen -t vim       0  vim $HOME/todo.txt 
screen -t ipython   1  ipython
screen -t finch     2  finch
screen -t mutt      3  mutt
screen -t top       4  top

chdir $HOME/Repos/git
screen -t CL        5   
screen -t git       6
```

If you actually want to be able to save a session that you're in you might consider using screen-session.

https://github.com/skoneka/screen-session

> Session saver currently supports saving of: layouts, scrollbacks,
>   titles, filters and is able to restart programs run in windows. It
>   recognizes regular, group and zombie windows. Currently there is no
>   support for serial and telnet window types. By default, session saver
>   also tries to save Vim sessions using ":mksession" and ":wviminfo".
>
> Session saver accesses important data by directly reading /proc
>   filesystem  and sorts processes by parent pid. There is almost no
>   "stuffing" of commands  into windows (except when saving Vim sessions)
>   so there is no interaction  with programs itself.
>
> During session loading, every new window starts with
>   screen-session-primer (a small C program) which displays a list of
>   processes and asks user what to do: whether to start none, some or all
>   of window's processes or directly starts programs provided
>   "--force-start [win_num]" option was used.